# Создание Spring- проекта в IntellJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, maven

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда создаю Spring проект в таком виде(как на картинке) - все отлично работает, но решил подключить  Maven, не прописывал никаких зависимостей, ничего, просто pom.xml с базовыми тегами, и программа стала выдавать ошибку "beans.xml doesn`t exist" , добавил в мавен зависимости для подключения спринга - ничего не изменилось тот же "doesnt exist". Насколько понимаю в Ultimate IDEA, при создании спринг-проекта, он автоматически подключает все необходимые зависимости, но не понимаю почему при добавлении мавена - он перестает видеть мой beans.xml. Буду очень благодарен за ответ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы создаете проект с помощью IJ, то она добавляет только те зависимости, которые соответствуют шаблону для выбранной библиотеки.

Структура [Maven-проекта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) несколько отличается от структуры проекта созданного IJ и зависимости находятся в pom.xml. Они не будут доступны в IJ проекте пока вы не сделаете импорт Maven-проекта в IJ, или же пока вы не установите авто-импорт во всплывающем окне.

То, что касается `beans.mxl` если это [конфигурация спринга](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-metadata), то его можно подключить в фейсет, когда IJ обнаружит что есть конфигурация спринга.