# Как организован проект по папкам у профессионалов?

Tags: java, spring

Всем привет, я только в начале пути, java учу сам, сейчас пишу свой небольшой проект на Spring никогда не работал программистом и даже не видел как всё организованно. Периодически беру платные консультации и во время одной из них мне сказали что у меня неправильная структура проекта.

Как у меня организовано сейчас, пакеты:

controller
dto
models
repo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё. И в самих контроллерах я и пишу код
Но мне сказали что так нельзя, и лучше методы выносить отдельно.
А как делают профессионалы? Какая структура считается правильной? Вы создаете еще один пакет и в нём класс со всеми методами или там много классов, или структура вообще не такая?

Comment: Классы можно группировать по разному, по назначению, по фиче, по какому то архитектурному соображению. Класс со всеми методами не приветствуется, такой класс тяжело поддерживать. Если хотите узнать больше о проектировании классов, почитайте книгу Роберта Мартина «Чистый код»

Comment: [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/892977/204920) можно найти то что нужно ля создания структуры проекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом - структура правильная.

Единственное, обычно добавляют пакет `services`, в нём хранятся классы с бизнес логикой обработки запросов.

И ваши контроллеры (из пакета `controller`) должны обращаться к сервис-классам из пакета `services`.

Возможно, ваши коллеги именно это и имели ввиду, то есть контроллер только для того, чтобы перехватить запрос и вызвать сервисы для обработки. Код обработки из контроллера нужно вынести.